# RMDateSelectionViewController com UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c

Quero colocar o componente [`RMDateSelectionViewController`](https://github.com/CooperRS/RMDateSelectionViewController) no meu projeto. Quero que ele apareça quando o usuário tocar no `UITextField`. Mas não estou conseguindo, segui o código de exemplo e não deu certo.

Segue meu código:

```obj-c
- (IBAction)openDateSelectionController:(id)sender {

    RMDateSelectionViewController *dateSelectionVC = [RMDateSelectionViewController dateSelectionController];
    dateSelectionVC.delegate = self;

    [dateSelectionVC show];

    dateSelectionVC.datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime;
    dateSelectionVC.datePicker.minuteInterval = 5;
    dateSelectionVC.datePicker.date = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:0];
}
```

E a mensagem de erro:

> Error: -[RMDateSelectionViewController showFromViewController:] has been called with an instance of UITableViewController as argument. Showing the date selection view controller from an instance of UITableViewController is not possible due to some internals of UIKit. To prevent your app from crashing, showing the date selection view controller will be canceled.

Alguém sabe como resolver isso??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como explicado pelo autor do controle no github, não é possível apresentar o RMDateSelectionViewController de um UITableViewController, mas somente de UIViewController devido a complicações com o framework da apple 'UIKit'. Aqui ta uma foto da explicação.

[image: GitHub]

Nesse site tem algumas outras alternativas para solucionar o seu problema.
https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=date

Comment: Rafael, era isso mesmo. Vou pesquisar outro componente para testar aqui.